# Node.Js: Trying to access a ruby gem inside node app on heroku

Tags: ruby, node.js, heroku

I am trying to use this https://github.com/mooktakim/image_optim_bin on my Heroku application, and I'm really not sure as to how to do it. Right now I have the following code trying to run `pngcrush`

```
exec('pngcrush -rem gAMA -rem cHRM -rem iCCP -rem sRGB ' + file + ' ' + file, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('PNGCRUSH OUTPUT: ', error, stdout, stderr);
});
```

But it results in the following error on my `heroku logs` output:

```
PNGCRUSH OUTPUT:  { [Error: Command failed: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'image_optim_bin' (>= 0) among 9 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
```

This is my `Gemfile`

```
gem 'image_optim_bin', :git => 'https://github.com/mooktakim/image_optim_bin.git'
```

This is the first time I've tried using ruby gems inside a nodejs application so I really am unclear of how to do so. Is there a specific directory I need to target to run the `gem`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you already using Heroku [multi buildpacks](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) to support both Node and Ruby? If so, I recommend running `heroku run bash` and then trying to execute `pngcrush` from the command line. You should be able to quickly identify the path you need.